# Cannot open backup device error - inaccessible folder for backup

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019

I cannot run backup jobs or commands when using folders OTHER than the ones specified in SQL Server Properties, here: [image: SQL Server Properties]
Only those the backup can be saved to.

For example:

```
BACKUP DATABASE myDB
TO DISK = @name
   WITH FORMAT,  
      MEDIANAME = 'Z_SQLServerBackups',  
      NAME = 'Full Backup of myDB';
```

We have a new installation of SQL server 2019 on same machine (previously version 2016).

I have tried various suggestions from dba.stackexchange ([e.g. this one](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/282240/cant-take-backup-to-the-shared-folder)) or internet:

1. multiple user accounts on SQL server agent (all of them have access to any location tried)
2. create credentials for the backup job failing on *"Cannot open backup device"*

I am desperate, any suggestion on how to enable saving a backup to any local disk/network location will be appreciated very much

Comment: multiple user accounts on SQL server agent (all of them have access to any location tried)

Have you tried the user account on the SQL Server Engine, which creates the backup. Not the Agent account.

Comment: @Peter which one [from these](https://mtsslovakia-my.sharepoint.com/:i:/g/personal/miroslav_polgar_mts_sk/EUAHhnlfjTVIurCeqF9YCX4Bv5ZDqlhqJfPxebYo5c0owQ?e=IMMkXB) is the Engine?

Comment: The one in blue

Comment: That is a significant change, all suggestions I have seen talk about SQL Server Agent. Do you please have an official Microsoft manual on this?

Comment: What happens when you run your example backup script manually?...if you get the same error, then it's not a SQL Agent permissions issue and Peter might be right. The SQL Server service in Windows runs under a dedicated account. That account is effectively who permission checks get funnelled through when operations occur outside of SQL Server (such as accessing a file share).

Comment: Backups are done by the Engine, not Agent. Agent may act as a job scheduler, but it connects to the engine and runs the T-SQL needed. You can run XE or trace to see this, you don't need an official document.

Comment: And if you set the ACLs for the SQL Service [NT Service\MSSQLSERVER] for a default instance, and still are having issues, you can use procmon to observe all the file system calls, along with the identity making the calls to see what fails.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon

Comment: @J.D. the same error when running backup query from console.   
`NT Service\MSSQLSERVER` is the account on SQL Server Service.

Comment: So what do you guys suggest to allow the backups to be saved in other locations?

Comment: @Myro, you should check file system permissions to assure your SQL server service account have full access to the folder you mentioned in configuration and to all subfolders and files.

Comment: @Mainecoon21 how could this account be used for saving to a network location, as it is just a local one? Shall I change it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to grant write and modify access on the folder of interest to NT Service\MSSQLSERVER. Basically, right click the folder go to properties, security, click on edit the click on add. Enter the service name as shown below and click ok. Cross check to ensure read and modify permissions are marked for NT Service\MSSQLSERVER

[image: sql permission]

Comment: I cannot grant it on a network folder though and that is crucial for me. It used to work before on a different installation I do not have an access to anymore.

Comment: For a network folder grant access to the computer account eg `YourDomain\ServerName$`, or use a Domain Account to run SQL Server and grant the permssions to that.  Also drive letter mappings are per-user.  When backing up to the network use a UNC, eg `\\servername\sharename\folder\file.bak`

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft this computer account YourDomain\ServerName$ does not exist. The network folder is actually a Synology, so the user has to be from domain. I will have to change the account running the sql service, but I am afraid of some unknown consequences

Comment: I changed the account to a domain one that had required permissions and it works. Thanks